# Converting axios requests from localhost to heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, axios, mern

I'm trying to design a simple MERN stack spreadsheet app, and I'm currently stuck with getting my GET and POST requests to work when deployed to Heroku. While it works with no problems locally (locally, backend server goes to http://localhost:4200), the problem is I don't know what address it *should* be going to once deployed to Heroku.

I've tried having it have a relative URL, but then it breaks on both localhost and Heroku - localhost will default to http://localhost:3000 instead of the needed http://localhost:4200, and on heroku, it goes to *http://[spreadsheet-app].herokuapp.com* but both produce 404 errors.

I have also tried setting up a config var on heroku, baseURL which I set to the *[spreadsheet-app].herokuapp.com* URL, but it seems that that URL is completely skipped, telling me it's still somehow undefined, so I'm not sure:

a) What URL I need to set up for heroku to get my GET and POST requests to work

b) How to proceed if there isn't a straightforward answer for a)

Here is how my relevant code is currently set up for a GET request:

```
componentDidMount(){
let base = process.env.baseURL || "http://localhost:4200";

return axios({
  method: "get",
  url: base + "/chars",
})
.then(res => this.props.getChars(res.data))
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does your app contain both your client and Node apps? So the Node app is being deployed to the same Heroku app?

Comment: Can you see what the value of `base` is inside of your production built application code?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody - Yes, my client is in /backend_server in the root folder so it would be deployed with the Node app to Heroku.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev - It comes up as "http://localhost:4200" - the process.env is an Object with only the variables, NODE_ENV & PUBLIC_URL.

Comment: If the backend has been deployed, and is running, then you should be able to hit http://[spreadsheet-app].herokuapp.com/chars directly with your browser to ensure it's working.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if the backend on heroku is running. Is there something else I have to do, other than pushing all the code for it to heroku, for it to be running? Going directly to the api's url just shows me a blank page (with no errors in console), though if you mean hitting it as in successfully doing the GET and POST calls, it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure it's running. Checkout the Heroku docs for how to configure the deployment. Also, it sounds like you might not have `baseURL` setup in your environment variables. So make sure that's added as a configuration variable within your Heroku configuration with your Heroku dashboard.

Comment: Thank you, I'm in the process of trying to get it fixed. It looked like I was missing a Procfile to begin with, which is probably why my Express server was not running on Heroku.

As for the environment variables, it's strange because it does show up when I do `heroku config` to see if it exists, but seems to come up undefined when I try to access it in `process.env.baseURL`.